# How to post a form with array of view models that include Iformfile?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I'm trying to post list of PersonViewModel, It's working fine as long as the PersonViewModel does not have any IFormFile property.

Razor Page Model:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public PersonViewModel[] People { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        // Do something with People property
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Html Form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="People[0].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[0].LastName" class="form-control" />

    <input type="text" name="People[1].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[1].LastName" class="form-control" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, If I add an IFormFile to ViewModel and post the form again, The form will not reach the post action method.

ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; } = null;
}
```

Html Form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="People[0].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
    <input type="file" name="People[0].Photo" class="form-control" />

    <input type="text" name="People[1].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[1].LastName" class="form-control" />
    <input type="file" name="People[1].Photo" class="form-control" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Project Version: ASP.NET Core 2.2

Project Template: ASP.NET Razor Pages

Is there something that I'm doing wrong or is it related to the asp.net core?

Comment: In viewmodel your property name of `IFormFile`  is `ResumeFile`  but in view model you have `Photo`?

Comment: @hassan.ef Sorry, I was trying to simplify the real code. When I copied the real code, I forgot to change the property name.

Comment: A workaround for this is adding a separate `BindProperty` of type `List<IFormFile>`, so that you can upload the list of files separate from your list of `PersonViewModel` objects

Comment: @JoshWithee
Unfortunately, the real ViewModel I'm using for my project has more than one IFormFile property. I need to have strongly typed ViewModel or at least a workaround to detect each ViewModel's related files.

Comment: Relevant issues: 
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7719
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8527
Looks like someone might have solved it?

Comment: @JoshWithee,
I've read both these topics before. These topics are focused on binding to a collection of IFomFile that is used as a property of a view model or as an action method argument. binding to a collection of file was not possible before but It has been fixed since version 2.2. In my example, if I change the photo property to IEnumerable<IFormFile>, It would work.

Comment: @JoshWithee I guess, I need to create an issue on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I find a workaround by binding files to `List<IFormFile>` and assigning the value to `Photo` of `People`in a foreach loop.

I also find that it only works when the model binding ignores the `Photo` property using `[BindNever]` attribute.

Refer to my below demo:

ViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [BindNever]
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

PageModel:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{

    [BindProperty]
    public List<PersonViewModel> People { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<IFormFile> FileLists { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {

    }

    public void OnPost()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < People.Count; i++)
        {
            People[i].Photo = FileLists[i];
        }
        //var formFile = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        // Do something with People property
    }
}
```

View:

```
<form method="post" id="typea" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="People[0].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[0].LastName" class="form-control" />
    <input type="file" asp-for="FileLists" class="form-control" />


    <input type="text" name="People[1].Name" class="form-control" />
    <input type="text" name="People[1].LastName" class="form-control" />
    <input type="file" asp-for="FileLists" class="form-control" />

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, This might work. But the problem is that in my project I have more than one IFormFile property. In some cases, I have nested ViewModels that each one contains a couple of IFormFile property.